# replace all occurrences of a sub string between 2 charcters using sql

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Input string: `["1189-13627273","89-13706681","118-13708388"]`

Expected Output: `["14013627273","14013706681","14013708388"]`

What I am trying to achieve is to replace any numbers till the '-' for each item with hard coded text like '140'

Answer (score 0):

Use [`regexp_replace(text,text,text)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html) function to do so giving the pattern to match and replacement string.

First argument is the value to be replaced, second is the POSIX regular expression and third is a replacement text.

---

**Example**

```
SELECT regexp_replace('1189-13627273', '.*-', '140');
```

Output: `14013627273`

---

**Sample data set query**

```
SELECT regexp_replace(value_to_replace, '.*-', '140')
FROM (
  VALUES ('1189-13627273'), ('89-13706681'), ('118-13708388')
  ) t(value_to_replace);
```

*Caution! Pattern `.*-` will replace every character until it finds last occurence of `-` with text `140`*.

Comment: *until it finds first occurence of -*  No, it searches for the last `-` char.

Comment: Instead of `.*`, I think you need `[^.]*`.

Comment: @kamil I tried it and I am always getting the last element of the array only like "13515637"]"

Comment: @MohamedAbdelHakim I don't see this element in your sample data. Please edit your question with information of how your data is stored.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT replace(value_to_replace, '-', '140')
FROM (
  VALUES ('1189-13627273-77'), ('89-13706681'), ('118-13708388')
  ) t(value_to_replace);
```

check this

Answer (score 0):

I found the right way to achieve that using the below regular expression.

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE (string_to_change, '\\"[0-9]+\\-', '140')
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regexp for this, it's as easy as concatenation of `140` and the substring from `-` (or the second part when you split by `-`)

```
select '140'||substring('89-13706681' from position('-' in '89-13706681')+1 for 1000)

select '140'||split_part('89-13706681','-',2)
```

also, it's important to consider if you might have instances that don't contain `-` and what would be the output in this case